# How can chrome or electron launch default mail client

Tags: google-chrome, electron, mailto

When I use **mailto** to launch default mail client, I find that if outlook is closed in Windows 7, **mailto** only launch outlook editting page, not outlook self. So I cannot send the email via only clicking send button. I must launch outlook by myself. But I still find I don't need to launch MAC default email client to send email in MAC.

Could anybody know how to deal with this occurrence? Thank you very much.

Comment: It appears problem is with email configuration

Comment: @Sudarshan, How can I configure it? Could you give me some suggestions?